# Css move a higher object with hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am doing an interactive menu where the boxes move according to which we pass our mouse on it, it works mostly but when for example I want to switch to `#yo4` I cannot translate on `#yo`, apparently this is because the one is bigger than `#yo4` but I don’t see how to solve this problem.

```css
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}

#yo {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 750px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#yo2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

#yo2:hover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -34px;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

#yo2:hover+#yo3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 536px;
}

#yo2:hover~#yo4 {
  width: 213px;
  height: 50px;
}

#yo3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

#yo3:hover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -39px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#yo4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 268px;
}

#yo4:hover {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="yo"></div>
  <div id="yo2"></div>
  <div id="yo3"></div>
  <div id="yo4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please be more specific and clear. I still got no idea what you actually try to do, what supposed to be happen... The question might be very clear to you, for others that have picture in mind at all, it is not.

Comment: I’m sorry about that. What I try to do is a menu around a rectangle where there are squares all around and when I pass on a square this one gets bigger and will move the other squares by reducing them. It works in its entirety but I get a problem that is when I want to move a square that is lower in my code example: `#yo4:hover + #yo2 { position : absolute; width: 70px; height: 40px; left : 536px; }`. It’s not going to take into account the amendment, and I don’t know how to do that.